# This Page can't be found after URL rewrite in IIS

Tags: ssl, url, iis, url-rewriting

I've followed  [This](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https) URL to convert HTTP to HTTPS and still it's showing  "This page Can't be found" when i type my site name directly. But, works when i append HTTPS to my URL. Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it results in "This page can't be reached". It means that "too many redirects". So you need to modify the rule to avoid the infinite loop.

you could use below URL rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
     <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

{REQUEST_URI} contains URL's path, including the query string with a leading slash.

also check your iis site binding with Http and https. make sure you bind the correct certificate.

you could use below PowerShell command to create a self-signed certificate:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName www.sample1.com -CertStoreLocation cert:Localmachine\My
```

and move that certificate to trusted root folder.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]